# SUID not running as file owner

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, suid

I'm trying to check how the SUID works, and I have created a binary with the `shc` compiler from this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm the script"
sleep 5
cat /srv/test/secret
```

The binary is owned by user `kali` (`/usr/bin/hehe`). I added execution permissions and the SUID bit.

```bash
.rwsrwxr-x kali kali 15 KB Fri Feb  9 00:49:58 2024  /usr/bin/hehe
```

I'm trying to execute it with `franlol` user.

As far as I understand, with the `s` bit, the file should be run by the user `kali` because he is the owner, even if it is executed by user `franlol`.

Why the binary/script cannot do the `cat` to a file owned by the same user than the binary owner?

What is not correct in this flow?

```bash
┌──(franlol㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lsa -l /srv/test/secret
.rwx------ kali kali 26 B Fri Feb  9 00:46:01 2024  /srv/test/secret
                                                                                                                                       
┌──(franlol㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lsa -l /usr/bin/hehe   
.rwsrwxr-x kali kali 15 KB Fri Feb  9 00:49:58 2024  /usr/bin/hehe
                                                                                                                                       
┌──(franlol㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ hehe
I'm the script
cat: /srv/test/secret: Permission denied
```

Also, while the execution is doing the 5s sleep, If I do a `ps aux | grep hehe` I see that the execution user is not Kali, and as far as I understand, if the `hehe` script is owned by the user `kali`, it should be run by the same owner.

Comment: Is the partition mounted with the `nosuid`option?

Comment: AFAICT shc binaries still use the shell to execute code, and bash doesn't respect setuid usage.